How to build a prime curve having a specific a prime order or an order containing a specific prime divisor?
There’s algorithms for computing curves’s order from prime curves or even algorithms for building binary curves containing a specific order through torsion.
But if I want a prime curve having or containing a specifc prime order $n$ how to compute the curve’s parameters ? Or how to alter Weierstrass curve $A$ having $n$ for getting a different Weierstrass prime curve $B$ also containing $n$ ? (so likely on a different prime field)
In each cases, the resulting curves doesn’t have to be secure at all…

If "the resulting curves [don't] have to be secure at all," your Question may lack essential nexus with cryptography.  You might explain the motivating application to clear that up.

@hardmath the underlying idea is to then try to find a lift from a secure curve even if it s turns to be impossible.

All elliptic curves over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ have points in the range of Hasse bound which can be written as $q+1 - 2 \sqrt{q} \leq #E \leq q+1 + 2 \sqrt{q}$ where $#E$ is the number of points on the curve. Thus there is only one way: brute force with different values of $a$ and $b$

@madhurkant I read all papers that provide more clever ways than bruteforce but still have exponential agortithms.

@user2284570 Thanks for clarifying that there exist clever ways.

@madhurkant an other point is such paper tried to generate curves that are secure whereas in my case supersingular or anmalous curves or curves with with wiefriech prime modulus are Ok. So I think it migh be easier.

@madhurkant https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/S1793042117500099
